# Esperanto and Dvorak keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, dvorak

So, I'm fully aware on how to type characters with various accents (å, à, ø, á, ä and â) but one thing I don't understand is how to type those accents when typing in Esperanto. The circumflex, for instance, will only work with vowels (â, ê, î, ô, û) but Esperanto uses a different set of special characters. These would be ĉ, ĝ, ĥ, ĵ, ŝ and ŭ (which can be described as c, g, h, j and s circumflex and u breve) and apart from copying them from other pages on the web or popping open the Emoji and Symbols panel, I am at a loss on how to type these in Dvorak and since I have near exclusively typed in the Dvorak for the last two years, I'm not really too enthused to switch back and forth to Qwerty just to type one character every so often. It, like popping open the "Emoji and Symbols" panel, is simply unrealistic and really breaks my flow.

So, any suggestions on a work around that is actually much simpler?

Just in case you may need to know, I'm running OS X 10.11.1 on a late 2013 15" Retina MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a custom keyboard like Dvorak Extended, an example of which is found at

http://fwvdijk.org/

Or create substitutions for the needed characters in system preferences/keyboard/text

Comment: Let's see... Ĝ, Ĝ, Ĥ, Ĵ, Ŝ and Ŭ... ā, ø, á, ä, à, â... It's a bit different typing French characters already but I'll get used to it. Thanks for the advice. :)